# Hyperlink in fancy header not pointing to correct page

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr, labels, hyperlink

This is my `main.tex` file (adding it as whole here because I don't know what might be conflicting):

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside]{extbook}
\usepackage{adforn} % ornaments glyphs adforn font
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ #1}{}}% produces numofchapter.numsection name of section now
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}% produces numofchapter.numsection.numofsubsection name of subsection now

\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead{}%
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \large{%
        \hyperref[Index]{Index}% Point to index, always present. Works correctly
        \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\nameref{\chaptername::\thechapter}}{}}{% Point to chapter now, only if chapter isn't empty
            \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\value{chapter}}{0}}{% Point to chapter now, only if it's number isn't 0
                \ \adforn{43}\ % Symbol >
                \hyperlink{\chaptername::\thechapter}{\thechapter\ \nameref{\chaptername::\thechapter}}% The hyperlink.
                \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\firstleftmark}{}}{% Point to section now, only if it isn't empty
                    \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\value{section}}{0}}{% Point to section now, only if it's number isn't 0
                        \ \adforn{43}\ % Symbol >
                        \hyperlink{section::\thesection}{\firstleftmark}% The hyperlink.
                        \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\value{subsection}}{0}}{% Point to subsection now, only if it's number isn't 0
                            \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\firstrightmark}{}}{% Point to section now, only if it's number isn't 0
                                \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\firstleftmark}{\firstrightmark}}{% Point to subsection now, only if section and subsection don't have the same name
                                    \ \adforn{43}\ % Symbol >
                                    \hyperlink{subsection::\thesubsection}{\firstrightmark}% The hyperlink.
                                }{}%
                            }{}%
                        }{}%
                    }{}%
                }{}%
            }{}%
        }{}%
    }%
}%
\fancyfoot{}%
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    \large{%
        \thepage%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index} \label{Index} \tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction} \label{chapter:Introduction} \label{\chaptername::\thechapter} \lipsum[1-3]
\newpage \section{Overview} \label{section:Introduction/Overview} \lipsum[1-5]
\newpage \section{Problem statement} \label{section:Introduction/Problemstatement} \lipsum[1-4]
\subsection{Context} \label{subsection:Introduction/Problemstatement/Context} \lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The section and subsection hyperlinks don't point to the correct pages, instead point to the first page of the document (probably a default behavior when something isn't working). Everything compiles correctly.

Renders to:

[image: This is how it is rendered to]

Comment: your document is way to large and it can't be tested anyway because of the \input. Reduce your problem to a sensible size.

Comment: Thank you. I made an edit to have a minimal working example without inputs but with all the rest that might cause a conflict.

Comment: no sorry, that is not enough. You can easily test if a package is relevant or not.

Comment: Ok, made it to 50 lines. Removed all that wasn't related. The problem persists.

Comment: You are using the wrong destination names. Why should something like `section::\thesection` exist? The names created by hyperref are e.g. `section.\theHsection`, but actually that won't work neither. You are referring to numbers in the header which are not reliable due to the asynchronous page breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [Ulrike Fischer' solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610746/hyperlink-in-fancy-header-not-pointing-to-correct-page/610755#610755)
and mixing it to what I already had, my final working solution with all edge case handling is the following:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\myhyperlink{mm}{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}% New line
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\myhyperlink{section.\theHsection}{\thesection\ #1}}{}}% Changed
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\myhyperlink{subsection.\theHsubsection}{\thesubsection\ #1}}}% Changed

\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead{}%
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \large{%
        \hyperref[Index]{Index}%
        \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\nameref{\chaptername::\thechapter}}{}}{%
            \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\value{chapter}}{0}}{%
                \ \adforn{43}\ %
                \hyperref[\chaptername::\thechapter]{\thechapter\ \nameref{\chaptername::\thechapter}}%
                \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\firstleftmark}{}}{%
                    \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\value{section}}{0}}{%
                        \ \adforn{43}\ %
                        \firstleftmark% Changed
                        \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\value{subsection}}{0}}{%
                            \ifthenelse{\not\equal{\firstrightmark}{}}{%
                                    \ \adforn{43}\ %
                                    \firstrightmark% Changed
                                }{}%
                            }{}%
                        }{}%
                    }{}%
                }{}%
            }{}%
        }{}%
    }%
}%
\fancyfoot{}%
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    \large{%
        \thepage%
    }%
}%
```

Comment: this doesn't work. You can't do things like `\ifthenelse{\not\equal{\value{subsection}}{0}}` in the header. You are forgetting that LaTeX has already processed part of the next page when it will set the header and so the subsection values can be one off. That is why the mark system exists.

Comment: I know I don't know that much but compiling it, it works. Trial and error... it works.

Comment: well "works" isn't quite correct. Here a page that I created with your code, and as you  can see the subsection is missing in the header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaCjq.png

Comment: That's the intended result. When there is no subsection declared yet (but there is a section), the if conditions  insert the section in the header, but not the subsection. In your example the subsection starts near the end of the page, so that result is the aspired one.

Similarly with chapter and section.

My only doubt is on the Preface chap header - if that chap' counter is set to a val of 0 (being before chap 1. Intro). Or what happens in the 1-2 pages just before the Appendices - there the counter is set to 0 (to be incremented for each next declared appendix - in letters, A, B, ...).

Comment: well if this is the intended result, then this here is wrong: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soHsB.png.  Sorry but your code will for quite similar pages sometimes show the subsection and sometimes not. And it doesn't matter if the subsection is near the end or at the begin of the page.

Comment: Hmmm you are right. That's not consistent. How do I solve it with \markboth{}{} in \chaptermark's redefinition? Could you please write a brief example or link to some answer that does that? Thanks again

Comment: The standard LaTeX `\mark` commands can't solve this problem. I might have a solution for you (using a not yet released package), but I want to be sure about the specifications. From your postings I deduce:
The header consists of 4 parts: A ➤ B ➤ C ➤ D, where A=Index, B=Chapter, C=Section and D=Subsection. (1) if the chapter doesn't have any sections thus far (i.e. up to the current page), the C and D are empty (2) otherwise C will be the first section on the current page, if there is one, otherwise the last section on previous pages in the current chapter.

Comment: (3) if the current section has a subsection on the current page, D will be the first subsection (`*`) on this page, otherwise the last subsection in the current section on previous pages, if there is any. If the current section doesn't have any subsections, part D will be empty. (4) If a part is empty, the preceding ➤ will be omitted.
(`*`) Not sure what happens if the page starts with a subsection from the previous section followed by a new section, but no subsection following that one. Will the subsection be used for D, or will it be omitted?

Comment: (0?) Correct. (1) Correct. (2) Correct. (3) Correct. ( * ) If C will be chosen to be the last section of the previous pages, then D shall be it's subsection at that point. Otherwise if C were to be chosen as the new section, D must be "this page's new section"'s subsection (if exits) or empty. (#1) In any case a section C having a numbering X.Y. must always be followed by a subsection D with numbering X.Y..Z. (Z > 0) or empty D. (X, Y, Z being sectioning numbers; X might also be an appendix letter.).

Comment: (#2) Ideally one would be able to extract all the needed information from a page's first element (part, chap, sect, subsect etc) numbering. X gives us B, Y gives C, Z gives D. (#3) The problem is which elements are first in a page is "dynamically defined" (don't know the correct word) by latex.

Comment: P.s: (#1a) So X.Y. followed by X.(Y+1).(some Y subsection) is not correct.

Comment: (#4a) An opposite direction lookup might be to obtain each element's (part,chap,sect,subsect etc) pagenumber (some sort of dictionary); (#4b) sort them (edit. not needed probably); (#4c) for each page where a breadcrumbs header will be placed, get the deepest element (X. has depth 1, X.Y. has depth 2, X.Y.Z has depth 3 and so on...) with X.Y.Z. smallest of all the numberings of that depth; (#4d) Place that element to the right most part of the header and extract it's parents (to be placed leftwards) from it's numbering... (#5) Check this answer out too: tex.stackexchange.com/a/122910/214687

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the time to sort out all the details, but in the core you must pass the hyperlink through the mark commands if you want to get the right header. Comparing the numbers is not reliable.

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside]{extbook}
\usepackage{adforn} % ornaments glyphs adforn font
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\NewDocumentCommand\myhyperlink{mm}{\ \adforn{43}\ \hyperlink{#1}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\myhyperlink{section.\theHsection}{\thesection\ #1}}{}}% 
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\myhyperlink{subsection.\theHsubsection}{\thesubsection\ #1}}}% 

\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead{}%
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \large
        \hyperref[Index]{Index}% Point to index, always present. Works correctly
        \firstleftmark \lastrightmark
    }%
\fancyfoot{}%
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    \large{%
        \thepage%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index} \label{Index} \tableofcontents \markboth{}{}
\chapter{Introduction} \label{chapter:Introduction} \label{\chaptername::\thechapter} \lipsum[1-3]
\newpage \section{Overview} \label{section:Introduction/Overview} \lipsum[1-5]
\newpage \section{Problem statement} \label{section:Introduction/Problemstatement} \lipsum[1-4]
\subsection{Context} \label{subsection:Introduction/Problemstatement/Context} \lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem of the not working hyperlink but this way are lost all the controls on (sub)section number 0 or empty... In some pages this produces breadcrumbs like IndexCONTENTSCONTENTS which is not intended

Comment: simply make the marks empty with \markboth{}{} in the right places (e.g. at chapters) like I did after \tableofcontents.

Comment: The document is long and complex, with appendices and stuff - so manually setting \markboth{}{} in selected pages is error prone. Thank you again. I posted a mixed solution with your `\NewDocumentCommand\myhyperlink` and my previous edge case handling

Comment: why manually? define \chaptermark to do this.